# Terraform : How to capture the public IP of the aws_instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

**Scenerio :** I'm trying to capture the public IP of the aws_instance I'm using to use within an executing shell script

*I have the following code*

```
resource "aws_instance" "k8-control-plane" {
  count                  = 1
  ami                    = "ami-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  iam_instance_profile   = "blah-user"
  subnet_id              = "blah-xxxxxx"
  key_name               = "blah-bot"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.blah-sec-grp.id]

  #Execute on remote instance
  user_data = <<-EOF
  #!/bin/bash

  #DEBUG
  echo ${self.public.ip} >> ~/my_ip.txt 

  # Run kubeadm
  kubeadm init --token "${local.token}" --token-ttl 15m --apiserver-cert-extra-sans ${self.public.ip} --pod-network-cidr "192.168.0.0/16"

  # Prepare kubeconfig file for download to local machine
  kubectl --kubeconfig /home/centos/admin.conf config set-cluster kubernetes --server https://${self.public.ip}:6443
  EOF
}
```

**Problem:** I cannot figure out how to inject the corresponding public IP of the aws_instance (as denoted above ${self.public.ip}). Obviously this is wrong so I'm not sure how this is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[self](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/syntax.html#the-self-object) can only be used in provisioners, not `user_data`. But you can use [instance metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html):

**Update based on comments: should be private ip, not public ip:**

```
resource "aws_instance" "k8-control-plane" {
  count                  = 1
  ami                    = "ami-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  iam_instance_profile   = "blah-user"
  subnet_id              = "blah-xxxxxx"
  key_name               = "blah-bot"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.blah-sec-grp.id]

  #Execute on remote instance
  user_data = <<-EOF
  #!/bin/bash

  #DEBUG
   
  private_ip=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)

  echo $private_ip >> ~/my_ip.txt 

  # Run kubeadm
  kubeadm init --token "${local.token}" --token-ttl 15m --apiserver-cert-extra-sans $private_ip --pod-network-cidr "192.168.0.0/16"

  # Prepare kubeconfig file for download to local machine
  kubectl --kubeconfig /home/centos/admin.conf config set-cluster kubernetes --server https://$private_ip:6443
  EOF
}
```

Comment: This still did not work for some reason. It didn't echo anything and the other command were blank where this was referenced

Comment: @stackoverflow There could be mistake in the user data script it self. Can you please ssh to the instance and check `~/my_ip.txt ` and `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` files?

Comment: @stackoverflow If you run manually `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4` does it output the ip? Maybe your instance does not have public ip?

Comment: ~/my_ip.txt doesn't even get created. Should i be referencing instance metadata variable called $public-ipv4 instead?

Comment: @stackoverflow Are you certain the that the instance have public IP? Not all instances have it. The curl and metadata link are correct. Also what AMI are you using? Is it amazon linux 2?

Comment: @stackoverflow user_data executes as root, so check in root folder, not ec2-user.

Comment: My mistake the ~/my_ip.txt does get created. It was in roots home. Strangely the file is indeed blank though. And yes I'm using a plain centos7 AMI

Comment: @stackoverflow Can you run `curl ifconfig.me` to verify the public ip?

Comment: The curl ipconfig.me did return with an IP. I think i need the $private_ip instead here

Comment: @stackoverflow private ip can be obtained `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4`. This also is empty?

Comment: This returned with an IP

Comment: @stackoverflow That's good. I will update the answer to use private ip then.